# My python code won't run outside of my IDE

Tags: python, windows-7, matplotlib

The following code runs fine in my IDE (PyScripter), however it won't run outside of it. When I go into computer then python26 and double click the file (a .pyw in this case) it fails to run. I have no idea why it's doing this, can anyone please shed some light?

This is in windows 7 BTW.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  axes3d,Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter

import Tkinter
import sys

class E(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent


        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.dest)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
        ax = Axes3D(self.fig)



        u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

        x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
        y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
        z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))





        t = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4,color='lightgreen',linewidth=1)




        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)

        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both')


        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)



        self.btn = Tkinter.Button(self,text='button',command=self.alt)
        self.btn.pack()

    def alt (self):
        print 9
    def dest(self):
        self.destroy()
        sys.exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = E(None)
    app.title('Embedding in TK')
    app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to import the module in the command line and got the following warning.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, validate_toolbar
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 168, in <module>
    class Scheduler(threading.Thread):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
>>>
```

**EDIT(2)**

I tried what McSmooth said and got the following output.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import threading
>>> print threading.__file__
threading.pyc
>>> threading.Thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
>>>
```

Comment: Do you see an error message, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Please provide either error messages or a description of how it fails to work.

Comment: There are no error messages. As far as failing to work it just wont open up. No window appears.

Comment: So, you double-click, and nothing at all happens? How strange. Does the icon show the python logo, or is it just the unknown filetype icon?

Comment: Yes, it shows the python logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unless you've been messing around with your standard library, it seems that you have a file named `threading.py` somewhere on your python path that is replacing the standard one. Try:

```
>>>import threading
>>>print threading.__file__
```

and make sure that it's the one in your python lib directory (it should be`C:\python26\lib`). If it's not the right file that's getting imported, then you'll have to rename the fake one to something else. If it is the right file, then try:

```
>>>threading.Thread
```

and see if that throws an exception in the REPL.

### update

That's weird. on my system, it gives the name of the source file. either save as a file or run at the command line the following code to find it.

```
import os.path as op
import sys

files = (op.join(path, 'threading.py') for path in sys.path)
print filter(op.exists, files)
```

Comment: Your code bought up this ['C:\\Python26\\Lib\\threading.py'] and a program I made with the same name, however I changed it's name and still having problems.

Comment: Rename the `threading.pyc` file in the same directory as the "program" you made "with the same name".

Answer (score 1):

From Windows command shell get into python shell by typing python binary (you should get something like '>>>'). Here type **import matplotlib** (your package name which you are trying to import), if you get an error like **ImportError: No module named matplotlib** that means as Matthew F suggested you need to update your PYTHONPATH (either in User specific env or in Windows System env) otherwise post the error message that you are getting while running the script.